# Lambda functions do not trigger after cognito events

Tags: vue.js, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I'm trying to implement an authentication workflow using AWS Cognito in order to sync my users table (Hasura graphql backend) with Cognito users, but the post confirmation Lambda does not trigger. The code of the Lambda function is as follow:

```
const axios = require('axios');

exports.handler = async (event,context,callback) => {
  console.log(event);
  const id=event.request.userAttributes.sub;
  const name=event.request.userAttributes.username;
  const email=event.request.userAttributes.email;
  
  const hasuraAdminSecret="####"
  const graphAPI="####"
  const body = {
    query: `
    mutation insertUsers($userId: String!, $userName: String!, $userEmail: String!) {
    insert_users(objects: {cognito_id: $userId, email: $userEmail, username: $userName}) {
      affected_rows
    }
  }
  `,
    variables: {
      userId:id,
      userEmail:name,
      userName:email
    }
  }
  var  response = {};
  await axios.post(graphAPI, body, {
    headers: {'content-type' : 'application/json', 'x-hasura-admin-secret': hasuraAdminSecret}
    })
  .catch(err => {
    console.error(err.data);
    response=err.data;
  })
  .then(res => {
    console.log(res.data);
    response = res.data;
  })
  
  callback(null,event);
}
```

The code for the signup and the confirmation pages are as follow:

```
import { Auth } from 'aws-amplify';
export default {
    name:'Signin',
    data(){
        return {
            username: undefined,
            email: undefined,
            password: undefined,
            code: undefined,
            user: undefined,
        }
    },
    methods: {
        confirm() {
            // After retrieveing the confirmation code from the user
            Auth.confirmSignUp(this.username, this.code, {
                // Optional. Force user confirmation irrespective of existing alias. By default set to True.
                forceAliasCreation: false
            }).then(this.$router.push("/"))
              .catch(err => console.log(err));
        },
        signup(){
            Auth.signUp({
                username:this.username,
                password: this.password,
                attributes: {
                    email: this.email,
                    name:this.username
                },
                validationData: [],  // optional
                })
                .then(data => this.user = data.user)
                .catch(err => console.log(err));
        }
    }
    
}
```

When signing up the user is created and confirmed in the AWS console, but the lambda function is not triggered (no logs in Cloudwatch and no errors from Cognito). Where should I look ?

Comment: I would like to point that the Lambda works fine when tested using the console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once the new user `signup` through `aws-cognito` you can call `lambda functions` using `trigger`

***Step 1:*** Open your `aws-cognito` `User Pools` under `general setting` click on `trigger`

[image]

***Step 2:*** You can customise the `workflow` with `triggers`. You can call your `lambda` function

- Pre sign-up
- Pre authentication
- Custom message
- Post authentication
- Post confirmation
- Define Auth Challenge
- Create Auth Challenge
- Verify Auth Challenge
- User Migration
- Pre Token Generation

***Step 3:*** Select your workflow trigger `Post confirmation` and you can see the list of `lambda` functions. You have to select the `lambda` function.

[image]

**Adding Cloudwatch:**

***Step 1:*** You have add role under `Configuration` under `Permissions`  tab
[image]

***Step 2:*** Edit the `role` and attach `policy` for `CloudWatch` and `CloudWatch Logs`

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your detailed response.
Just wanted to add that cloudwatch logs did not appear because I had wrong lambda permissions.

Comment: @9rnt I updated the answer for adding cloudwatch to your lambda function. Hope it will helps you.